# C# thread hangs on close file

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread that calls a static method to update file properties using WindowsAPICodePack ShellPropertyWriter and BackgroundWorker.  The thread calls the method below for each file in a folder of 1000+ files and hangs on the ShellPropertyWriter.close() after the 700th update or so.

Nothing to do with the file itself, tried using different files that successfully updated before.

```
    public static bool ShellPropertyUpdate(VideoEntry mediaEntry)
    {
        try
        {
            ShellFile mediafile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(mediaEntry.FilePath);
            ShellPropertyWriter pw = mediafile.Properties.GetPropertyWriter();
            pw.WriteProperty(SystemProperties.System.Music.Artist, mediaEntry.Actor);
            pw.WriteProperty(SystemProperties.System.Music.Genre, mediaEntry.Genre);
            pw.WriteProperty(SystemProperties.System.Rating, mediaEntry.Rating);
            pw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void mnuWriteMetadataToFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs ev)
    {
        this.WorkerThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.WorkerThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(WorkerThread_WriteMetadataToFiles);
        this.WorkerThread.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(WorkerThread_ProgressChanged);
        this.WorkerThread.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => WorkerThread_Completed("Writing metadata to files", s, e);
        this.WorkerThread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this.WorkerThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        this.WorkerThread.RunWorkerAsync(WMPlayer);
    }

    private void WorkerThread_WriteMetadataToFiles(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        MediaPlayer wmp = (MediaPlayer)e.Argument;

        // ... Loop with the foreach video in the library and write it to file.
        foreach (VideoEntry entry in wmp.Videos)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                worker.ReportProgress(counter, "Updating '" + entry.Filename + "'" + Environment.NewLine + "Processing file");
                if (VideoToFile.ShellPropertyUpdate(entry))
                {
                    result &= true;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
        e.Result = result;
    }
```

Comment: Good question. Can you reproduce it everytime? Any difference with Debug vs Release modes? Whats the calling code, just a `foreach(file in directory`? Can you put in a tiny `Thread.Sleep(50)` and tell us if that makes a difference? Does running it on the main thread work? Is there any correlation to the file sizes to where the thread hangs?

Comment: I am not sure if this information is going to be sufficient to troubleshoot the hang.. I mean it's possible that the API pack has bug.. but it is also possible that bug is in your code elsewhere, which we don't see above.. Code you have shared seems pretty straightforward.. Without looking at rest of the code, either yours, or the API pack, it's hard to say.. IMHO, You'd get mostly guesses, unless you add more detail.

Comment: I can reproduce it each time and it hangs on or a bit after or before 700 file update. I'm on Debug x86 (will try Release). The calling code loops through for each in List<VideoEntry>. I'll try sleep and main thread and let you know. No correlation with file from what I saw, I tried swapping different files in the list and got the same end result.  I'm sure the bug is in my code somewhere as I'm using TagLib to update ID3v2 tags and the same results happen when closing the file there two but happens at around 300+ updates. I'll add calling code above.

Comment: Tried a sleep(100) nothing changed. Release mode tiny change processed few more files. Running under the main thread didn't change things either. It must be the files themselves, I'm going to run a more exhaustive analysis on files.  I would've thought that even if there's anything wrong with a file an exception would be thrown but there's nothing, just a hang!

Answer (score 3):

Never heard of this assembly before, but it smells like handle exhaustion to me. Try this instead:

```
using (ShellFile mediafile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(mediaEntry.FilePath))
{
    ShellPropertyWriter pw = mediafile.Properties.GetPropertyWriter();
    pw.WriteProperty(SystemProperties.System.Music.Artist, mediaEntry.Actor);
    pw.WriteProperty(SystemProperties.System.Music.Genre, mediaEntry.Genre);
    pw.WriteProperty(SystemProperties.System.Rating, mediaEntry.Rating);
    pw.Close();
}
```

Here every file handle is closed immediately, instead of at garbage collector's discretion. `ShellFile` must implement `IDisposable` for this to work, otherwise this code will not compile. I'm fairly certain that `ShellFile` implements it.

Comment: ShellFile does implement IDisposable. I just tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work, same behavior still. it's a cleaner way to implement the method anyways. thanks

Comment: Apparently it does have something to do with the files themselves.  I took out few problem files and the Thread continued processing until the next problem file.  I have no clue what's wrong with the file, however I'm willing to pass on updating problem files. Is there a way to stop/kill the thread? I can't use DoWorkEventArgs.cancel() since the thread is hanging and not coming back.

Comment: @stackmonkey nice, and you should make it an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it does have something to do with the files themselves. I took out few problem files and the Thread continued processing until the next problem file. I have no clue what's wrong with the file, however I'm willing to pass on updating problem files. Is there a way to stop/kill the thread? I can't use DoWorkEventArgs.cancel() since the thread is hanging and not coming back.